# call oracle function with parameters

Tags: sql, oracle

I started to learn pl/sql.I have problem with functions.I created a function like this

```
create or replace
 FUNCTION              GET_RANK_INFO(
 p_no               IN     VARCHAR2,
 p_date     IN     DATE,
 p_count   IN  NUMBER,
 p_cycle          OUT VARCHAR2,
 p_return_code         OUT INTEGER,
 p_return_desc         OUT VARCHAR2)
 RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
   .... --Some variable definitions
   ....

BEGIN

  ....
  ...

END;
```

I want to call this function like this

`select GET_RANK_INFO('12345',to_date('10/03/2019','dd/mm/yyyy'),null) from dual;` 
but it gives error like that  `the number of argument types invoked is incorrect`

I converted my calling to pl/sql block structure but my code gives still same error:

```
DECLARE
 p_no            VARCHAR2(200);
 p_date           DATE;
 p_count          NUMBER;
 p_cycle          NUMBER;
 p_return_code    NUMBER;
 p_return_desc    VARCHAR2(200);
 v_Return SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
 p_no   := '23';
 p_date  := to_date('10/03/2019','dd/mm/yyyy');
 p_count:= NULL;

 v_Return := GET_RISK_RANK_FN(
   p_no=> p_no,
   p_date  => p_date  ,
   p_count => p_count,
   p_cycle => p_cycle,
   p_return_code => p_return_code,
   p_return_desc => p_return_desc
 );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('p_cycle= ' || p_cycle);

  :p_cycle := p_cycle ;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('p_return_code = ' || p_return_code );

  :p_return_code := p_return_code ;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('p_return_desc = ' || p_return_desc );

  :p_return_desc := p_return_desc ;


  :v_Return := v_Return; --<-- Cursor
 END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a function is doubtful; it would be OK if it returned one value, but - returning it along with several `OUT` parameters smells very much like a **procedure** you should be using instead. So, here's an example of how to do it:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test
  2    (par_deptno in  number,
  3     par_count  out number,
  4     par_name   out varchar2,
  5     par_rc     out sys_refcursor
  6    )
  7  is
  8  begin
  9    select count(*), max(dname)
 10      into par_count, par_name
 11      from dept
 12      where deptno = par_deptno;
 13
 14    open par_rc for select * from dept;
 15  end;
 16  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_deptno dept.deptno%type := 10;
  3    l_count  number;
  4    l_name   dept.dname%type;
  5    --
  6    l_rc     sys_refcursor;
  7    r_deptno dept.deptno%type;
  8    r_dname  dept.dname%type;
  9    r_loc    dept.loc%type;
 10  begin
 11    p_test (l_deptno, l_count, l_name, l_rc);
 12
 13    dbms_output.put_line('count = ' || l_count);
 14    dbms_output.put_line('name  = ' || l_name);
 15
 16    loop
 17      fetch l_rc into r_deptno, r_dname, r_loc;
 18      exit when l_rc%notfound;
 19      dbms_output.put_line(r_deptno ||' - '|| r_dname ||' - '|| r_loc);
 20    end loop;
 21  end;
 22  /
count = 1
name  = ACCOUNTING
10 - ACCOUNTING - NEW YORK
20 - RESEARCH - DALLAS
30 - SALES - CHICAGO
40 - OPERATIONS - BOSTON

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

In case you *insist* on a function, oh well, here you are; as you can see, it is pretty much similar to previous example:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test
  2    (par_deptno in  number,
  3     par_count  out number,
  4     par_name   out varchar2
  5    )
  6  return sys_refcursor
  7  is
  8    l_rc sys_refcursor;
  9  begin
 10    select count(*), max(dname)
 11      into par_count, par_name
 12      from dept
 13      where deptno = par_deptno;
 14
 15    open l_rc for select * from dept;
 16    return l_rc;
 17  end;
 18  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_deptno dept.deptno%type := 10;
  3    l_count  number;
  4    l_name   dept.dname%type;
  5    --
  6    l_rc     sys_refcursor;
  7    r_deptno dept.deptno%type;
  8    r_dname  dept.dname%type;
  9    r_loc    dept.loc%type;
 10  begin
 11    l_rc := f_test (l_deptno, l_count, l_name);
 12
 13    dbms_output.put_line('count = ' || l_count);
 14    dbms_output.put_line('name  = ' || l_name);
 15
 16    loop
 17      fetch l_rc into r_deptno, r_dname, r_loc;
 18      exit when l_rc%notfound;
 19      dbms_output.put_line(r_deptno ||' - '|| r_dname ||' - '|| r_loc);
 20    end loop;
 21  end;
 22  /
count = 1
name  = ACCOUNTING
10 - ACCOUNTING - NEW YORK
20 - RESEARCH - DALLAS
30 - SALES - CHICAGO
40 - OPERATIONS - BOSTON

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `OUT` parameter in the function then it cannot be called from SQL query.

Also if there is any DML's inside the function, that function cannot be called in the SQL query.

You need to call this function from PL/SQL block.